# How can I hide xamarin label to property or something

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<Label x:Name="Step1" Text="1.Hello" Margin="20" IsVisible="False" ></Label>
```

I want to show this step1 text in android form.

So I declare

```
public bool VisibleCheck { get; set; } = true;
```

but I can't understand how to use it

Comment: Well with an auto-property like that, there's no way it'll know it needs to access your label..

Comment: You should bind the `IsVisible` property to your `VisibleCheck` property on your ViewModel.

Comment: <Label x:Name="Step1" Text="go." Margin="20" IsVisible="{x:Binding}" ></Label>  like this?

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the property from your view model to the IsVisible property in the label.
`<Label x:Name="Step1" Text="1.Hello" Margin="20" IsVisible="{Binding VisibleCheck}" ></Label>`